# Server 2012 R2 SMTP service not sending mail to non TLS servers

Tags: email, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, smtp, starttls

We have SMTP virtual server on server 2012 R2 server. I have configured it to use TLS connection. We do have real sertificate etc. Everything works fine except mail that is going to mail server which do not support TLS connections. Now those messages are delivered eventually to mart host, but with long (5-days) delay.

Is there any way we could route those non TLS connection messages to smart host 
immediately? Or perhaps configure SMTP service to send message without TLS if remote peer does not support TLS?

Any suggestions to use other lightweight SMTP software instead of servers SMTP service?